# Dynamically create React Navigation version 3 navigators

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, wizard

I'm trying to create a **multi-step form wizard** using version 3 of React Navigation by following this [tutorial](https://tech.decisiv.com/building-a-basic-wizard-using-react-navigation-9bbac377b52b). The tutorial describes dynamically creating a stack navigator using `createStackNavigator()`. This approach no longer works in version 3 of React Navigation and is listed in the docs as a [Common Mistake](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator). In version 3 of React Navigation `createStackNavigator()` should now be wrapped by `createAppContainer()` and an app should generally only have one [app container](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html).

How can I create a multi-step form wizard using React Navigation V3 that:

1. Receives an array of steps (React components)
2. Generates a progress bar
3. Generates a Next button on each screen and a Submit button on the last screen
4. Enables a way to save form state when navigating from one step to the next
5. Uses a [stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) to navigate between the steps so displaying the default right to left transition animation

A example of the desired result is shown below:

[image]

Comment: just create a normal stack navigator.

Comment: Each screen will have a form and each time Next is pressed the input data should be validated, any errors displayed, and finally stored. This seems to me like logic that should be abstracted, rather than repeated on each screen.

Comment: Hi, Matthew it has been almost a year. Do you find a way to do this? Any direction?

Comment: No I didn't. I've not looked deeply into it but I think writing a custom naviagtor might be the way to go. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/ I didn't have the time to go that deeply into it so I just created a normal stack naviagtor and abstracted my wizard as best I could. Not ideal but I had a deadline

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Understandable